# Losing disk space and fast

Tags: disk

I have a Fedora server with 300GB on the `/dev/xvda1` partition. I'm losing GB at a rapid rate. There is no way possible this is normal so I'm trying to figure out where this is coming from.

I'm not even using `du`, I'm just using `df -h` to see the drop of disk space and it is fast. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is rather vague. Logs probably, gadd to the question the output of `sudo du -h /var/log`

Comment: You should use `du` to identify large files on your filesystem. Chances are something is writing a lot to disk, and that's the cause of your issue.

Comment: Start by installing `ncdu` and using it to find out which directory is getting filled up so quickly. It will help us in identifying a possible cause, giving us a place to start looking.

Comment: A quick command for spotting a growing file (assumption is that it is open) could be `lsof -s | sort -nr -k 7 | head`

Comment: There is no simple way to do it.  Use `du` to locate the file that is growing.  Start from `/` (`du -hs /*`) then if you find that, say, `/usr` is growing, descend into subdirectories of `/usr` (`du -hs /usr/*`) etc.  In the simple case you'll eventually locate a single file, and you can use `lsof` to find out which process writes to it.  In more complicated scenarios you'll have a file that has been deleted on disk but it's still held open by a process. You'll need more advanved `lsof`-fu to deal with that.

Comment: Perfect, thanks guys. You were right du showed me exactly where the disk usage was happening. I narrowed it down to an error log and corrected the issue. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do, when I face such issue. This is not a rule, but just sharing my insights.

**1)**
Check output of `df -kh`, and confirm where is `/dev/xvda1` mounted. (lets say /var directory)

**2)**
If `/dev/xvda1` is filling up fast, then a lot of I/O will be happening over it.
Try and see output of `iotop` command (if you have), if not skip this step.

**2.1)**
If you do get the output of iotop, see the process which is doing maximum I/O on the screen. It should be one of the top ones if space is filling up so fast.
Note down the PID of the process.
Thereafter, check following
`lsof -p <PID> <---- PID that you noted down`
At the end of output of `lsof` command, you see something like

```
rsyslogd 1171 root    0u  unix 0xffff8800379e8700      0t0      11328 /dev/log
rsyslogd 1171 root    1w   REG                8,1   628182    3540277 /var/log/messages
rsyslogd 1171 root    2w   REG                8,1    27890    3540278 /var/log/secure
rsyslogd 1171 root    3r   REG                0,3        0 4026532040 /proc/kmsg
rsyslogd 1171 root    4w   REG                8,1     6375    3540279 /var/log/maillog
rsyslogd 1171 root    5w   REG                8,1    15228    3539742 /var/log/cron
```

Make a note of values as 0u,1w,2w etc. These are file descriptors opened by that process. One of the file descriptors will be one where data would be written pretty fast.

**3)**
Assuming that you do not have any other directory under /var directory mounted on a different block device, Do the following (if you do, ping in again, we might need some more information about your system)

```
cd /var <--- the directory which you saw where /dev/xvda1 was mounted.
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -hs {} \;
```

This will present you the highest space consuming directory in /var directory. May be you get some lead from there.

Let me know if something works out of this or not.

Disclaimer:
I am assuming that your `/dev/xvda1` is mounted directory on some directory and it is not part of some LVM,SWRAID etc. If above commands do not help anything (preferably if Step 1 has no output about /dev/xvda1), let us know we share more steps to investigate.